# Google App Engine Datastore Writes: How to enable/disable read-only mode remotely?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, readonly

In reading up on backing up [GAE's Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin), where:

> We strongly recommend that you set your application to read-only mode during a backup or restore...

After a cursory inspection, it *appears* that the only way to do this is via the GAE web admin UI, where you either **Disable** or **Re-Enable Writes** inside a page somewhere.

I would like to write some Ant buildfiles and/or shell and/or Python scripts that would allow me to backup/restore my GAE app's Datastore automatically. This would mean I would need a way to automate the enabling/disabling of writes (putting my app into and out from a "read-only" mode) to my Datastore, all from inside some script (like I said, either Ant, bash or Python).

So I ask: is this even possible? Or is this something that *must* be done "manually" (via the web admin UI)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Capabilities Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/capabilities/overview) is the one that you can use yo read the state of some capabilities of your app like DataStore writes. Unfortunately this Api only have methods to read the state, but not for set the state.

**edited:**

---

Since the code must consult the Capabilities API to get the state of each functionality in the App-engine, and avoid failures by over-quota, system maintenance etc... One possible solution is to put a kind of interface in front of the Capabilities API within flags to disable each functionality.

pseudo code i.e:

```
class DatasToreWriteCapabiliti{
  boolean DATASTORE_WRITE = true;

  public disable(){ DATASTORE_WRITE = false;}
  public enable(){ DATASTORE_WRITE = true;}

  public CapabilityStatus status(){
     if(DATASTORE_WRITE == false) return CapabilityStatus.DISABLED;

     CapabilitiesService service = CapabilitiesServiceFactory.getCapabilitiesService();
     return service.getStatus(Capability.DATASTORE_WRITE).getStatus();
  }
}
```

Comment: Since setting the state (Enable/Disable Writes) is possible through the web admin app, I'm wondering if I can just use Firebug to look at the HTTP requests that get sent off when you set the state through the app. I may be able to recreate the requests and have them fired off from some script using HttpClient or something. I just wonder if this would violate my "terms of use" with App Engine. I don't see why it would, I wouldn't be using any API that they don't already publicly expose...can anyone weigh-in here?

Comment: @ 4herpsand7derpsago I don't know about "terms of use" but would be easier to put a kind of interface wrapping the Capabilities API within flags to disable or enable functionality, and make your code consult this interface. Your app must consult the Capabilities API to avoid failures so instead consult it make your code consult the new interface and enable disable functionality there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused by what it means by saying 'set your application to read-only mode': you think this is a service provided by GAE, but it actually means, in your app, you create a mode to prevent writes while you're performing backup.

I expect the optional read-only mode available from the Web interface is not designed for freezing during backup, but just managing the status of a datastore.